# Passing Dictionary to ObjectForScripting with WPF WebBrowser

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, expandoobject, comvisible

I am using a `WebBrowser` component in WPF to host some JavaScript + HTML and I want to be able to pass a customisable object in as the `ObjectForScripting` property.  My end goal is that the javascript running in the `WebBrowser` can call something like:

```
window.external['lookup'].getValue(someId);
```

I can achieve something close to this by implementing a class with `ComVisible` set to `true` that has a `lookup` property on it:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ScriptingContext
{
    public LookupService lookup { get; set; } //where LookupService is also ComVisible
}
```

However, I want to be flexible about the members on the `ObjectForScripting` that I'm passing in so I can't specify what each property will be beforehand.

Ideally I would like to just specify a name-object pair to pass in, but afaict this doesn't work.

What I have tried (and failed with) so far:

- using a `Dictionary<string,object>` as my context
- using an extension of `Dictionary<string,object>` that is marked as `ComVisible`
- using an `ExpandoObject`
- using a `List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>`
- using an extension of  `List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>` that is marked as `ComVisible`

Is there some way to pass a customisable `ObjectForScripting` into the WPF `WebBrowser` that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by customisable, but there's plenty of ways to accomplish what you're going for, such as building a wrapper for your dictionary and having that be your ObjectForScripting:

```
[ComVisible(true)] 
public class ScriptingContext 
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> objectsForScripting;
    public object GetValue(string s) 
    {
        return objectsForScripting[s];
    }
}
```

With the corresponding javascript `window.external.GetValue("lookup").getValue(someId)`.

Note that you can also pass ComVisible objects to javascript through the InvokeScript method and interact with them that way, using something like `webBrowser.InvokeScript("RegisterProperty", "lookup", lookupObject)` and manage the objects you're exposing on the javascript side.

Comment: Yup, that works.  Slightly ashamed I didn't try that myself - that's what I get for late night coding!